# Trouble clicking box without text using selenium python safari WebDriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink

I'm having trouble clicking a box using selenium on python. Im going to add all the info I can on here.

I am using the safari WebDriver.

The [first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFyww.png) here shows what the webpage looks like in inspect element mode. I am trying to click on the board titled "ANSYS".

This [second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pill.png) shows the box where the hyperlink is contained in. I am trying to click this hyperlink. My current code goes something like

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
boards_button = driver.find_element_by_class('board-tile')
boards_button.click()
```

My logic for using find_element_by_class is based on noticing that the hyperlink is inside the class "board-tile". I have also tried:

1. by_name('ANSYS')
2. find_element_by_link_text('ansys')
3. find_element_by_partial_link_text('ansys')

This [third picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Mq2.png) shows where the text is placed in the inspect element viewer.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can find whatever it is you're looking for by searching by the xpath. you can find the xpath go anything by right clicking the element and then get xpath on Apple inspect element window